# No overload variant of "next" matches argument type List[Scene]

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I get this mypy error `No overload variant of "next" matches argument type List[Scene]` when I am trying to check my following code.

```py
class Scene:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
    def something(self):
        self.a = 2

class Game:
    def __init__(self, scenes:List[Scene]) -> None:
        self.scenes = iter(scenes)
        self.current_scene = next(scenes)
```

How do I get rid of this? The error comes from the last line of the code. I have tried `self.scenes:Iterator = iter(scenes)` but even that does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to write a Python iterator, you need to provide certain "magic" dunder functions, such as `__iter__()` and `__next__()`. These functions are the ones called by those things that can iterate over a class.

For example, here's a class that returns all odd numbers in a range, much like `range()` returns all numbers in a range:

```py
class odd_range(object):
    def __init__(self, first_one, last_plus_one):
        # Ensure start at first odd >= given start, and
        # store terminator for later checking.

        self.__curr = first_one
        if first_one % 2 == 0:
            self.__curr += 1

        self.__term = last_plus_one

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # Terminate if range over, otherwise
        # return current, calculate next.

        if self.__curr >= self.__term:
            raise StopIteration()

        cur = self.__curr
        self.__curr += 2
        return cur
```

---

However, even if your `List` class provides that (and we can't tell for sure without the source), you may *think* that you are iterating over the list with the following code, but you are not:

```py
def __init__(self, scenes:List[Scene]) -> None:
    self.scenes = iter(scenes)
    self.current_scene = next(scenes)
```

You create an iterator `self.scenes` but the thing you are calling `next` on is the *original* collection `scenes` passed in to `__init__()`, *not* the iterator itself. If you wanted to use the iterator, that would be:

```py
self.current_scene = next(self.scenes)
```

Though you would be better off using a more descriptive name like `self.scenes_iterator` to better distinguish them.

Comment: but I am defining `List[Scene]`. Shouldn't that have `__next__` ? I have also tried with `Sequence` and `Iterable`. But those produces same error.

Comment: @Pritam: you would have to check the source code for `List`, that's not standard Python. However, you should keep in mind that a collection is *not* the same as an iterator over a collection. See the final part of my answer for more detail.